# How repair/uninstall Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer

I cannot uninstall Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2. When I was trying to uninstall the first time, the power went off to my machine and screwed up the Beta 2 installation. I cannot find a Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2 download on the Microsoft website any longer to repair the Beta 2 installation. How can I get VWD 2010 Beta 2 off of my system so I can install the new release?

Comment: This might do better on Super User.

Comment: The question is listed on SuperUser.com as well.

Comment: I am having a nice little excercise at Microsoft trying to get this solved if anyone wants to follow it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/a2f4d9c3-1a78-4ac1-b316-04c5727feb46/

Comment: Here is another person having the same issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550848/express-2010-beta-uninstall-express-2010-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after weeks of waiting, Microsoft finally came through via Scott Hanselman and Aaron Stebner. Below is a link to Beta 2 versions of the software that would not uninstall correctly for me:

- [Download Visual Studio 2010 Express Editions](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2009/10/21/download-visual-studio-2010-express-editions.aspx)

You can reinstall Microsoft Express Beta 2 software via the link above and then properly uninstall the software to use the new Microsoft Express Editions.

It's sad that I had to answer my own question here, but that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the keys from the registry and manually delete whatever is left in the Program Files folder.

> Run > regedit

Navigate to

> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

and delete the key(s) for VWD. If you're feeling confident you can also do a full registry scan and physically remove whats left of the application in Program Files.

Comment: There aren't any entries under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall for VWD.  The uninstall is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully uninstalled a failed Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2, I looked for nearly 2 weeks for the answer, and found it myself.

Answer:  You have to uninstall it from it's the setup.exe file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" directory, look for a folder called "vwd" or something similar in that directory, it should be in there (i didn't document it to well when I was uninstalling because I had tried nearly everything over and over with no results, and this just worked).  Running the uninstall from the cd or iso doesn't identify the location of the installed location and fails.  If you can't find the setup.exe file, do a search in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" directory.

Microsoft really ticks me off sometimes!

Comment: There are no VWD 2010 Beta 2 files on my system to remove. This solution didn't work for me.